# How to adding custom views around a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there a way to add custom views above and below a `UITableView`?

I'd like to have a custom *header* and a custom back button in the *footer*. What would be the  best to do this?

I've started by subclassing `UITableViewController` and tried resizing the `UITableView`. In vain.

Tried adding a new main view to `UITableViewController` and adding the `UITableView` as a subview to it. Result: table view won't appear at all.

Tried adding the back button as a subview to the table view, but it will get scrolled this way.

Now I guess it would be the best to somehow replace the "original" header/footer, but is that possible?

*Edit:* ***Solved!***

Using [this tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html), I've managed to add the required header and footer to the view using the Interface Builder.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please check it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I couldn't achieve what I wanted by code, but as noted in the edit of the original question, I was able to it using Interface Builder with the help of [this tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html).

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't the UITableView's tableHeaderView and tableFooterView properties do just what you want?

Comment: tableHeaderView / tableFooterView  moves together with the contents of the table, so unfortunately it's no good for me.